# sql - to increment the salary based on the Deisgnation

Tags: sql, oracle

In my application, I need a query with the following conditions.

1. Increase $1000 if the employee is a Trainee(A)
2. Increase $2000 if the employee is a Mechanic(B)
3. Increase $3000 if the employee is an Enginner(C)
4. Increase $5000 if the employee is a Manager(D)

I have the Table with the following columns

- Emploee_ID
- Employee_Name
- Emloyee_Salary_per_Month
- Employee_Salary_per_annum
- Emploee_designation (A, B, C or D)

Can anyone please tell me how to write an sql query for this condition?

Comment: You can use a CASE statement.

Comment: You should post your attempt at it and if this is homework you should tag it as such.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
update employee
set Emloyee_Salary_per_Month = Emloyee_Salary_per_Month +
                               case when Emploee_designation = 'A'
                                    then 1000
                                    when Emploee_designation = 'B'
                                    then 2000
                                    when Emploee_designation = 'C'
                                    then 3000
                                    when Emploee_designation = 'D'
                                    then 5000
                                    else 0
                               end
```

Comment: I would seriously consider adding an "else" clause for Employee_Salary_per_Month.  It would be a shame if other employees, who didn't get an increase or had a bad category, were suddenly null'ed out.  (Yes, I realize the question only mentions A, B, C, and D).

Comment: +1, but the shorter version would do a `set x = x + case....end`, so that you don't have repeat the addition and original value :)

Comment: Correct. I like even shorter statements :)